# Orphan constraints in SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, sql-drop, default-constraint

Running the following query results in all constraints in our client's database. However, several rows in the result set don't seem to have a parent, i.e. `parent_object_id = 0` and `OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id)` returns `NULL`.

```
SELECT name, type_desc, OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id), parent_object_id
FROM sys.objects
WHERE is_ms_shipped = 0
AND type_desc LIKE '%_CONSTRAINT'
```

Does this mean there are orphan constraints in the database? If so, how do I remove these?

From their names, I can see they are leftovers from before a large amount changes were made to the structure.

Comment: This should be impossible. Have you run have DBCC lately?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `sp_helptext` I can see they were created using a `CREATE DEFAULT` statement, e.g.:

```
CREATE DEFAULT dbo.MyDefault AS 2
```

This means they are simply unbound defaults, which can be bound using the `sp_binddefault` according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173565.aspx), and removed with a simple `DROP DEFAULT` statement:

```
DROP DEFAULT dbo.MyDefault
```

I wasn't aware of this syntax, which apparently will be removed in a future version of SQL Server, according to the aforementioned MSDN article.

Comment: Good call. I've not used this feature for many years and didn't think of it.